# I want to replace the screenshot on the recently used apps page with a still photo

Tags: java, android

I want to put a screenshot of my application on the recent apps page for a fixed photo for security reasons. I used the `FLAG_SECURE` method for this, but the screen of my application remains white on the recent apps page. I want to put a still picture instead of a white image. According to my research, the `onCreateThumbnail` method was also used, but it was deprecated by Google. The image I received is as follows :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateThumbnail(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Canvas)) onCreateThumbnail method was never working.

What can you do is to add a blocker layout in XML file of Activity or Fragment. So when Fragment or Activity is going in onPause method you show it and in onResume hide it using setVisibility method. This is much easier if you have single activity app so you will need to do it only in Activity class.